# How to install mongolid through composer?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, composer-php

I try install mongolid through composer and have error:

```
composer require leroy-merlin-br/mongolid
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
Could not find package leroy-merlin-br/mongolid at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

how to install ? 
ubuntu 14 and php 7

Comment: can you please give us the package link?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty https://packagist.org/packages/zizaco/mongolid

Comment: I added a answer a while ago . did you check that?

Comment: @user2495800 Did you actually read the page that you linked to? The installation instructions are right below the header of that page. (Hint: You have the wrong package name - don't translate any Github URL into a package name, always use the name from Packagist, because this is the only name Composer will know about).

Answer (score 1):

i think You don't have mongodb extension installed in your machine!

You need to install it using php pear

using

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

then run!

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

pecl install mongodb

echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```